# value of factory gets erased after page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this is my factory

```
app.factory('userFactory', function(localStorageService, $http, $rootScope) {       
    var myUser = {};    

    myUser.isCrazy = false;
    return myUser;
});
```

When user logs in, in the login controller I get some data from the db and decide  , using an `if/else` , if the user is crazy or not, so I have

```
  app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'localStorageService', '$location','userFactory','$rootScope',
  function ($scope, localStorageService, $location, userFactory, $rootScope ) {  
      userFactory.isCrazy = true;
        }
  ]);
```

and then, in another page's controller I show/hide divs , according to the `userFactory.isCrazy` (also true/false).

```
app.controller('anotherPageController' ,['$scope', '$filter', '$rootScope', 'userFactory','localStorageService',
        function ($scope, $filter, $rootScope, userFactory, localStorageService) {  

        if(userFactory.isCrazy == true){    
                    $scope.myMessage = true;
        } 

         }
     ]);
```

The html of `$scope.myMessage` is

```
<div ng-hide="myMessage">
```

Here is my problem.

After the login, `isCrazy` gets true. When I first visit the page, according to the `anotherPageController`, the message is hidden,  `isCrazy` is still true. All good.

If I hit refresh, `isCrazy` goes back to false and the message is no longer hidden.

What am I missing here? Why `isCrazy` is not keeping its value?

Thanks

Comment: because you refreshed the page, that's why.

Comment: @Jai So, is there a way, to keep a var persistant, dispate refreshes, using only Angular? Thanks

Comment: use `$localStorage`.

Comment: _"another page's controller"_ means a controller on another page. Are you sure you mean that or is it rather another controller on the same page? Because the former would have the same effect as a page refresh.

Comment: @zeroflagL No, I actually mean a controller on another page. Anyway, I will use `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is not save the value. For that you have to use at least local- or session storage to keep these values.

Comment: So, is there a way, to keep a var persistant, dispate refreshes, using only Angular? Thanks

Comment: I see you are using localStorageService. It can bring you possibility to store that values like that:

localStorageService.set(key, val);

var val = localStorageService.get(key);

Comment: Yes, I will use localStorageService after all, I dont see another solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just create a cookie with that value. Search the `setCookie API`. You can do it with JavaScript or PHP, as you wish.
If you still want to do it with angular js, check the   [angular-js cookie API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)  .

Comment: Aha, thanks man. I already use `localStorageService`.  So, is there a way, to keep a var persistant, dispate refreshes, using only Angular? Thanks

Comment: ´setCookie´ is not framework-dependant. Is a JavaScript predefined function.